# Unable to fetch the data between 2 dateTime

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, dataframe

```py
from pymysql import *
import pandas.io.sql as sql
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

current_date = date.today()
print(current_date)

current_date2 = current_date - timedelta(1)
print("Yesterday was: ", current_date2)

# connect the mysql with the python
con = connect(user="root", password="12345", host="localhost", database="test")

df = sql.read_sql('select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "2020-11-15" and datetime1 <= '"current_date"' ', con)
# print the data
print(df)
```

When I try to pass the `DateTime` as a variable then it generates an error:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "current_date2" and datetime1 <= current_date ': (1525, "Incorrect DATETIME value: 'current_date2'")

Comment: pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= current_date2 and datetime1 <= current_date ': (1054, "Unknown column 'current_date2' in 'where clause'")

Comment: Database table containing datetime1 Column with date and time values 2020-11-15 08:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`'select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "2020-11-15" and datetime1 <= "{0}"'.format(current_date)`

It should look like this now

`df = sql.read_sql('select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "2020-11-15" and datetime1 <= "{0}"'.format(current_date), con)`

if 2 parameters then:

`df = sql.read_sql('select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "{0}" and datetime1 <= "{1}"'.format(current_date2,current_date), con)`

Comment: df = sql.read_sql('select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >="{0}".format(current_date2)  and datetime1 <= "{0}"'.format(current_date), con)




Generates Error



pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= 2020-12-07".format(current_date2) and datetime1 <= "2020-12-07"': (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that

Comment: If you want to set 2 dates then use:

df = sql.read_sql('select * from tbl1 where datetime1 >= "{0}" and datetime1 <= "{1}"'.format(current_date2,current_date), con)

Comment: "It Works for Me"

Answer (score 0):

No need to make variable current_date just use CURDATE() inside select.

```
conn = pymysq.connect(user,psswd,db,host)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime1>'2020-11-15' AND datetime1<=CURDATE()")
df = cursor.fetchall()
print (df)
```

Comment: startdate ="2020-11-15"


enddate ="2020-11-30"


df = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime1>' "startdate" ' AND datetime1<= ' "end_date" ' ")